# how do I add a date with a number?

Tags: php, date

I have this date: `1348-10-11` and I have this number: `1438438368`. Now I want to know how can I plus them ? like this:

```
(1348-10-11) + 1438438368 =  1394-5-10 = current date as [Solar]
```

`1348-10-11`**:** the base of Solar date in *TIMESTAMP*. It is also equal with `1970-01-01` (as Gregorian)

`1438438368`**:** Total seconds of `1348-10-11` till now.

anyway for converting {Gregorian date} to {Solar date} I need to add a date with a number, Is it possible ?

Comment: I guess there is no built in functions (in mysql) for Persian calendar  but there are some custom functions  [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlpersiandat/?source=typ_redirect) which will do the conversion part you are looking for

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid ok thanks. just how do you undrestand that I need to Persian calendar ?

Comment: have a look at http://www.iranchamber.com/calendar/converter/iranian_calendar_converter.php

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid How did you figure out I need to Iranian calendar ??

Comment: By googling simple :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `date()` and `strtotime()` to convert date to timestamp then combine both.

```
$time = strtotime("1348-10-11") + 1438438368;
echo date("Y-m-d", $time); // Current date
```

[Here](http://3v4l.org/At2fq) is a demo.